# Not able to show image in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have added a image folder in webapp/images. Structure of app is

```
MyApp
 --src
   --main
     --java
--webapp
  --images
```

This is what I am doing in jsp `<img src="images/siteIcon.png"/>`. Can someone help me, what exactly I am doing wrong here. I am using IntelliJ

Comment: what's the url of the jsp page that contains this image tag? e.g. if it's `example.com/foo/bar/baz.jsp`, then your image tag will cause the browser to try and fetch `example.com/foo/bar/images/siteIcon.png`

Comment: http://localhost:8080/foo.jsp

Answer (score -1):

Your path to the image should start with a slash. Like:

```
<img src="/images/siteIcon.png"/>
```

Comment: You probably need to add the context path to the image src. Something like: <img src="/{contextPath}/images/siteIcon.png"/>

Comment: Dont you need to have an WEB-INF folder i your webapp? And then your images folder in the WEB-INF folder..